# How to get different records from two tables with different columns using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I am having problem with SQL. I want to get the different records from two different tables with different number of columns, which have the same primary key. 
I have tried "EXCEPT" and "MINUS", but since the two tables have different number of columns, I received errors.

Is there any other sql commands that I can use to get the records that I want?

Thanks,
Min

Comment: How about JOINS ? http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ Can you show your code ?

Comment: use inner join. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use INNER JOIN Like:

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column3
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column1=table2.column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT t1.table1column1,
       t1.table1column2,
       t1.table1column3,
       t2.table2column1,
       t2.table2column2,
       t2.table2column3
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.table1column1 = t2.table2column1`

Answer (score 0):

A FULL OUTER JOIN with key columns equal to NULL conditions can help you solve your issue.
Here is the sample SELECT statement

```
/*
create table Tab1(id int, col1 varchar(10))
create table Tab2(id int, col2 varchar(10), col3 int)

insert into tab1 select 1,'Kodyaz'
insert into tab1 select 2,'Vader'
insert into tab2 select 2,'Star Wars', 6
insert into tab2 select 3,'SQL', 2014
*/
select * 
from tab1
full outer join tab2 on tab1.id = tab2.id
where 
tab1.id is null
or tab2.id is null
```

I hope it helps,